# swift2 cannot get the error response properly

Tags: ios, swift, response, swift2

```
    var response: NSURLResponse?
    var resData: NSData?

    do{
     resData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response)

      } catch let responseError{
        print(responseError)
    }
```

When the authentication is successful, ios can parse the response correctly which has everything in it like status code. But when the authentication fails, it gets 'nil' response. Anyone knows the reason? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

When authentication fails, I suppose it's https authentication failure you experienced, in this case, the server doesn't respond anything as body of the http response, instead, the error code is returned in the header of the http response. Thus, you got nil as responseData. You should check the error and handle it gracefully.

Comment: When the auth fails, the response (which is a NSURLResponse) is nil, and I don't know where is the status code located at.

Comment: `class func sendSynchronousRequest(request: NSURLRequest, returningResponse response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?>, error: NSErrorPointer) -> NSData?` Check this **NSErrorPointer**